# Concurrent AJAX requests appear to delay each other

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-deferred

I have a form that queues up parallel ajax queries using essentially this pattern:

```js
var req1 = $.Deferred();
$.ajax("...", {type:'GET', data:form, /*...*/, success:function(){ req1.resolve(); }});
var req2 = $.Deferred();
$.ajax("...", {type:'GET', data:form, /*...*/, success:function(){ req2.resolve(); }});
// etc...
$.when(req1, req2, /*etc...*/).done(function(){/*...*/});
```

This performs terribly. Profiling shows that the handlers start executing in parallel server-side, but only after having caused each-other significant, mysterious delays.

When I first tackled this ticket, there were 12 queries (two sets of 6 identical queries) taking ~15 seconds each.

[image]

Profiling showed that the delay (~14 seconds) occurs sometime *after* jQuery had kicked off all of the 12 requests, but *before* the first line of any C# handler was ever called.

---

As it turns out, each request was being sent twice, so I started by fixing that, and it disproportionately lowered the shared overhead to ~4 seconds each.

[image]

If I send just any one of the 6 required requests, it completes in well under a second.

---

So here I am unable to imagine why kicking off multiple requests have this compounding overhead request. Every similar issue I've found online was reportedly fixed by the `SessionState` setting, so I was very disappointed to find it already in place in our solution. It is (has been) set to `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` on all our controllers. I also tried `.Disabled`, since this control doesn't use the session in any way, but that doesn't seem to be the problem in this case.

Besides that most common suggestion, we don't generate any request logging that I'm aware of or have anything else that should be writing to disk, adding any overhead, or otherwise locking on multiple concurrent requests coming into the IIS server.

Any thoughts on where I should dig next would be much appreciated.

Comment: An update on this. From the MVC side, I've learned we're using a dependency injector called "Ninject". This doesn't show up in the stack traces, but runs before the controller code. It was adding a lot of overhead, and the solution is specific to Ninject (use a static kernel) - but long story short, I should have profiled the server-side as well to help myself come to this conclusion.